# How can I open a file with a Chrome Web App?

Tags: windows, google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions, progressive-web-app

I am trying to open a specific file type (not html files or web links) with a Chrome Web App. Through some registry edits, I have managed to set the web app to be the default for the file type, but I am having issues with the open command of the web app. I am trying to open the file in the web app like this:

```
"C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome_proxy.exe" --profile-directory=Default --app-id=<app-id> --single-argument %1
```

However, with this command, when I am double clicking my file, the web app does show up, but it doesn't seem to try to open the file in any way. If I instead drag the file onto the web app when it is already open, the web app does handle the file. Is my command wrong or does the web app lack the code necessary to open files in this way?

Edit: I believe `--single-argument` is not even a supported option for `chrome_proxy.exe` since it doesn't seem to matter if it is there or not and `chrome_proxy.exe` seems to simply disregard any options it does not know such as literally `--whatever` instead of failing if called with invalid options. I originally thought `--single-argument %1` would be useful since this is how the system passes regular html files to `chrome.exe`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have a PWA to test on, but this is what I know.

The following setting in Chrome is required to enable a PWA to access files:

- Run Chrome
- Open `chrome://flags`
- Enter in the Search field "File Handling API".
  This will also find "File Handling Icons".
- Set both to Enabled using the drop-down menu
- Relaunch Chrome.

Try to open a file using the PWA by selecting the PWA in the Windows 10
file manager’s "Open With" menu.
You should get a dialog where you will need to allow this access.

Comment: I have enabled the two flags in Chrome and relaunched. When trying to right-click --> `Open with... <my-PWA>` the same behavior happens: The PWA opens but doesn't attempt to open the file. I'm not going to scoff at a GUI answer if this turns out to be the only way to do it, but, if possible, I would prefer an answer that deals with the CLI part of Chrome.

Comment: Try : add to the `chrome_proxy` call the parameter `--enable-features=FileHandlingAPI`, in case the chrome flags are not enough.

Comment: I tried `chrome_proxy.exe --profile-directory=Default --app-id=<app-id> --enable-features=FileHandlingAPI %1`, `chrome_proxy.exe --profile-directory=Default --app-id=<app-id> --enable-features=FileHandlingAPI --single-argument %1` and `chrome_proxy.exe --profile-directory=Default --app-id=<app-id> --enable-features=FileHandlingAPI --single-argument=%1`. They all behave the same as before when double-clicking the file (PWA opens, file does not).

Comment: For each of the options listed in the previous comment I also tried `right-click --> Open with... <PWA-registry-entry-I-created-which-uses-the-listed-CLI-commands>` and `right-click --> Open with... <Chrome-created-PWA-shortcut-in-Start-menu>`. These open the PWA but not the file as well.

Comment: I have installed a demo PWA for which "Open with" of a file works fine. For comparison, here is the command-line that it uses for opening the file : `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --profile-directory=Default --app-id=ihbbilocmhaiggehjogpljjcliglflho --pwa-launcher-version=99.0.4844.74 "C:\Temp\tmp.txt"`. Perhaps you should change your call to do the same. The PWA itself is [morning-bubbly-chauffeur](https://morning-bubbly-chauffeur.glitch.me/) and its source is available.

Comment: I think something is going terribly wrong on my machine because I tried your example PWA and 2 other PWAs and the best result is that Chrome opens the PWA and it has a note in the top-right corner of the title bar that the PWA can edit the file, but I still have to click on `Open file` in the demo PWA or on `Upload and open...` in the Office PWA for them to really load my file. I even reinstalled the Office PWA after enabling the file handling flag in Chrome and it is set automatically as the default for .docx files, but double-clicking them does exactly the same as above.

Comment: Can it be some security setting or extension in Chrome (or Windows)?

Comment: I disabled all Chrome extensions and Windows Defender and the behavior is the same. I can't think of any other security setting in either Chrome or Windows that could impact this. Nonetheless, I think I will go ahead and accept your answer as this seems to be the way to do it, even though it doesn't work for me specifically.

Comment: For more information, try perhaps to create a Windows VM, totally vanilla standard, and check if it works in there. Start perhaps with my demo PWA, before installing Office.

Comment: I uninstalled Chrome, purged my registry of all references to it, installed it again, installed the demo PWA you linked to as the first and only PWA in the system and double-clicking a .txt file now does indeed bring the PWA up with the file loaded. Everything else seems to be PWA specific. Thank you for your help!